# parameter management in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, parameter, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to pass a bunch of parameters to certain C++ class which is indirectly called in a ros2 node:
[image: image description]

Some parameters can be modified in runtime via HMI or other ways?

Since ros2 can only load parameters in yaml file from a node(if I understand correctively), is there a convenient way to pass these parameters around? I saw elsewhere that somebody suggests using database db file to store these parameters and use orocos rtt::service to load them.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410560/parameter-management-in-ros2/) by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2022-12-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There may be better ways, but we (at my company) tend to gravitate towards passing around the rclcpp::Node object and parameter namespaces. Then anything that needs to have some configuration can use the parameter namespace and node object to just declare it's own parameters and register callbacks for those parameter changes.

In cases where these classes are specifically ros-agnostic, we'll pass in a shared_ptr configuration struct into the non-ros classes. Then from the ros node, we can still declare parameters, and callbacks that change values in that shared configuration struct.

Added Examples:

Configuration Struct:

```
struct ClassNConfiguration
{
  int64_t field_a;
  std::string field_b;
}
```

ClassN:

```
class ClassN
{
public:
  ClassN(std::shared_ptr<ClassNConfiguration> configuration) :
      configuration_(configuration)
  {
    ...
  }
protected:
  std::shared_ptr<ClassNConfiguration> configuration_;
}
```

Node Class:

```
class MyNode : rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MyNode() :
      rclcpp::Node("my_node"),
      class_n_config_(std::make_shared<ClassNConfiguration>())
  {
    class_n_config_.field_a = declare_parameter("class_n.field_a", 42);
    class_n_config_.field_b = declare_parameter("class_n.field_b", "hello ros2");
    class_n_ = std::make_shared<ClassN>(class_n_config_);
  }
protected:
  std::shared_ptr<ClassNConfiguration> class_n_config_;
  std::shared_ptr<ClassN> class_n_;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2022-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on 2022-12-18**:
Thanks very much for your reply.

Could you please provide an example of the ***shared_ptr configuration struct***? I am not sure how to implement it.

Thanks for your kind help!

**Comment by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on 2022-12-21**:
Thanks a lot!